# Can someone explain the parameters of filter size, window size, and strides on the Conv1D layer of Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

After reading some documentations as well as answers regarding the topic, I've concluded a hypothesis on the meaning of the parameters which is depicted as below:
[image]

Is my understanding accurate? can someone elaborate more on the topic?? Thank you!